# Matplotlib_venn: weird output

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a script that makes a Venn diagram of 3 sets using the `matplotlib_venn` module, as follows:

```
union = set_1.union(set_2).union(set_3)
indicators = ['%d%d%d' % (a in set_1, a in set_2, a in set_3) for a in union]
subsets = Counter(indicators)

fig = plt.figure((n+1)*2 - 1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
v = venn3(subsets, (compare[0], compare[1], compare[2]), ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Here are two images I get out of this, from two different datasets with three sets each (one small and one large):

[image: A small data set]

In this image, The numbers are off. `180` should be in the middle and the `2` should be somewhere on the right side of the image, at the barely visible yellow/green part. I first thought this was due to the small size of the data set, but looking at the larger set ...
[image: A large data set]

... I can still see that the numbers are slightly off, although not as much as previously. The larger, common set is still not in the middle, and the other numbers seem to be a little off to where the "center" of their set is.

Any ideas as to why this is, and what can be done to remedy the problem?

Using the `venn3_unweighted` function rather than `venn3` shows perfectly nice (an non-proportional) images, including any `0`s in the smaller data set, but it just doesn't work with the proportional version.

Comment: The second example copes reasonably with the unusual data; and obviously copes less well in the first instance for the extreme case. I daresay their algorithm hasn't been tested at the extreme, so unless you want to change it, better off using non-proportional version.

Comment: Alright, I guess there's not much else to do then! Thanks anyway.